# Given a $3\times3$ board, how many ways are there to tile it with $1\times1$ and $2\times1$ tiles such that rotation is allowed?

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

Given a $3\times3$ board, how many ways are there to tile it with $1\times1$ and $2\times1$ tiles such that rotation is allowed.

The $1\times1$ tiles are colored red and the $2\times1$ tiles are colored blue. Note that the two tilings are identical.

> [image]

Although the left one is made of two horizontal $2\times1$ tiles the right one is made of $2\times1$ vertical tiles and are identical.
I managed to calculate a possible upper bound as $121$ and counted $118$ different possible tiling's manually however I feel like I've missed some. I've already tried searching for an answer through the internet but most of the things I've found are variations of this one. I thought about making a code that prints all combinations but unfortunately I have no idea on how id be able to code that.

Any help on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: By "rotation is allowed", do you mean that tilings that are identical up to rotation count as the same tiling or not? What about reflections?

Comment: I Should of been more clear but what I meant is that the 1x1 tiles are red tiles and the 2x1 tiles are blue and you are able to rotate the 2x1 tile to be vertical and horizontal so a blue square although can be made by vertical 2x1 tiles or horizontal 2x1 tiles they are still the same thing.

Comment: @IShotMyCat So you want the classes up to rotation of tilings by $1\times1$, $1\times 2$ and $2\times 1$ tiles of the $3\times 3$ grid?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio What I meant by rotation just means you can rotate the 2x1 title horizontally or vertically sorry if that wasn't clear. Basically if two tilings are identical in the way they are colored then they are the same tiling

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I don't really get what you are saying but I'll just restate the question better. Given a 3x3 board, how many ways are there to tile it with a 1x1 red tile, 2x1 blue tile and a 1x2 blue tile. Where tiling's that are colored in the same way are considered the same tiling.

Comment: What about whole rotations? Does rotating the whole of the first tiling you depict give a different tiling?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel If it looks differently colored than yes they are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mentioned that the two tilings are identical if they give the same color pattern. Essentially you're asking the number of colorings of a $3\times3$ board with blue and red such that the blue part can be tiled with $2\times1$ or $1\times2$ tiles without overlap.

From the $2\times1$ and $1\times2$ condition therefore you must satisfy the following

- An even number of cells are colored blue
- If we have a checkboard coloring of the board, exactly half of the blue cells land on blacks, and half of them land on whites
- There are no isolated blue cells

I have a quick script that checks the above conditions for all possible colorings and you can eyeball that all the resulting matrices are indeed proper.

Python [Code](https://onlinegdb.com/c_sumgbD4)

```
#Transforms a number to 0-1 list
def toBin(n, l):
    asd = [int(x) for x in bin(n)[2:]]
    return [0]*(l-len(asd)) + asd

#Transforms a list to a 3x3 list
def toM(lt):
    return [lt[0:3], lt[3:6], lt[6:9]]

#Quickly checks if the number is even and
#the checkboard condition is satisfied
#1 represents a blue cell
def quickC(m):
    tot = sum(sum(x) for x in m)
    if tot%2 != 0:
        return False
    bls = m[0][1] + m[1][0] + m[1][2] + m[2][1]
    if bls != tot/2:
        return False
    return True

#Helps the isolated vertex checking, if we reference
#an index outside the range, then returns false.
def gInd(m, i, j):
    if i<0 or j<0 or i>2 or j>2:
        return 0
    return m[i][j]

#Checks if i,j vertex is isolated
def checkIso(m, i, j):
    if m[i][j]==1:
        val = gInd(m, i+1, j)==0 and gInd(m, i-1, j)==0 and \
        gInd(m, i, j+1)==0 and gInd(m, i, j-1)==0
        if(val):
            return True
    return False

#Checks if there are no isolated vertices
def checkIsoAll(m):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if checkIso(m, i, j):
                return False
    return True

#Prints out a matrix in a nice and easy to understand form
def prM(m):
    s = ""
    for asd in m:
        sr = ""
        for dsa in asd:
            if dsa==1:
                sr += "#"
            else:
                sr += "-"
        s += sr
        s += "\n"
    return s

#Main code
total = 0
for n in range(2**9):
    m = toM(toBin(n, 9))
    if(quickC(m) and checkIsoAll(m)):
        total +=1
        print(prM(m)+"\n\n")
print("total number {}".format(total))
```

There are $98$ such tilings (colorings)

Comment: As you said, there can be no isolated blue cells. However, there also cannot be any blue regions with 3 cells. How did you handle cases with two blue 3-celled regions? (E.g. top and bottom row blue, middle row red). I don't see those in the output, which is of course correct, but you don't mention it.

Comment: +1, I also get 98 colorings (I generate all 131 possible tilings then count for those with distinct coloring by a program).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Indeed in a proper coloring all blue components must have even size. But note that for 3x3 it can never happen that we have odd but not 1 components, meanwhile having the checkboard condition satisfied. If the 3x3 grid is colored black and blue with top left being black, then the blue cells in your comment cover 4 black and 2 white.

Comment: @Lewwwer Ah, I didn't quite realise the impact of that property in this scenario. Nice!